# Pointers to debugging mid sized office wifi set-up

Tags: networking, router, wifi

We have a mid-sized office network (45 employees, 6 rooms, 8 indoor and outdoor wifi aps and several network switches) which has a problem in its wifi setup. Wifi connections become 'stale' every 5-10 minutes or so. Computers that are plugged into the switches work fine.

We built the network from the ground up and with whatever expertise we had on the dev team (not very much, I am the CTO of a relatively young Kenyan startup). We already looked at common wifi setup problems such as making sure the channels don't overlap, looking at the signal levels and using only access pointers no extenders. I am looking for pointers or reading material on how to deeply debug our wifi setup.

/var/log/messages on the dhcp server (which is also one of the access points) contains lots of lines like this:

```
Jul 27 15:55:56 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1259]: DHCPDISCOVER(br0) c4:c5:63:ae:09:71 
Jul 27 15:55:56 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1259]: DHCPOFFER(br0) 
192.168.0.164 c4:c5:63:ae:09:71 
Jul 27 15:55:57 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1259]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 
192.168.0.164 c4:c5:63:ae:09:71 
Jul 27 15:55:57 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1259]: DHCPACK(br0) 
192.168.0.164 c4:c5:63:ae:09:71 android-837125a7e2f69b3c
Jul 27 15:56:55 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1259]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 
192.168.0.205 e4:70:b8:62:71:2c 
Jul 27 15:56:55 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[1259]: DHCPACK(br0) 
192.168.0.205 e4:70:b8:62:71:2c DESKTOP-IV206H5
```

Comment: Whay exactly do you mean by "stale"? How is the wifi network set up (central wireless controller or individual)? How doe's the authentication work? Your starting point would be surely the Access Points or Controller logs.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I added /var/log/messages of one access points (the dhcpc server) above. When I say 'stale' I mean it looks like the connection is still active (there is an ip address, network manager shows the connection in whichever OS is installed on the machines) but e.g. a ping command will get stuck (i.e. no additional line gets added, it just stops and then after 5 or 10 minutes or so it resumes). It feels to me like a dhcp or ip address related issue but that would be weird as connections via cable are stable and don't have that issue.

Comment: Sorry if that is not the clearest explanation, I am not very experienced at debugging networks as I said ;-)